# What are valid deviceNames for Chrome emulation testing with selenium webdriver?

Tags: device-emulation, mobile-emulator

What are valid deviceNames for Chrome emulation testing with selenium webdriver?
And also where can i get the device width,height and user agent for the device?

Answer (score 1):

This is the device list:

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/mobile_device_list.cc

In Java you can get height and width values by this way:

```
initial_size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
height = initial_size.getHeight();
width = initial_size.getWidth();
```